# Uri Rest resource name formating

Tags: c#, rest, url, uri, dotnet-httpclient

I have resource I'm trying to retrieve with a GET opertaion

The resource look like this , the resousce is defined by user name 
which can contain domain information . i.e `var userName = @"Domain\myname"`
I'm having issues reformatting the Uri

what I've tried is to 
1. `var resource = string.Format("/user/{0}/order", Uri.EscapeDataString(userName ));`

2. `var resource = string.Format("/user/{0}/order", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName ));`

I'm sending data to back end using .Net `HttpClient` I get an error stating end point not found . when I look at the call at the debugger I see the endpoint 
is trying to be accessed: `user/Domain/myname/order`

what can be done , so a resource parameter could contain domain '`\'` characters

Comment: are you aware that the `"\"` in the `Domain\myName` the compiler sees the single back slash as an escape character.. why don't you split the username to just return `myname`

Comment: for the logic to work I user name must contain the domain name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a C# guy, so I don't know The Answer[tm], but I can tell you a few things to look for

1. String.Format is likely to be the wrong tool in the toolkit.  You aren't trying to format a string, you are trying to format a URI.  So you should be looking for something like a [UriTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uritemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. You should make sure that you know what the correct result is.  That's defined by the first appendix of the [URI specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).